# Error installing python-numpy

Tags: 15.04, python

On a virtual Linux box with Ubuntu 15.04 (freshly created) I am about to install python-numpy, but I get some error:

```
>sudo apt-get install python-numpy 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-numpy is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-texgyre libamd2.3.1 libdsdp-5.8gf libfftw3-double3 libglpk36
  libgsl0ldbl preview-latex-style python-cvxopt python-joblib python-patsy
  python-simplejson tex-gyre
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  texlive-fonts-extra-doc
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 233 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/60.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 76.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 229105 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../texlive-fonts-extra-doc_2014.20141024-1_all.deb ...
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Any idea how to fix this error? Is there a problem anyway as it says numpy is installed?

In addition to this error message I am required to run the command

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

every time I try to install something! What is going on...?

Additional information:

```
> dpkg -l | grep texlive
ii  texlive-base                                         2014.20141024-2ubuntu1                     all          TeX Live: Essential programs and files
ii  texlive-binaries                                     2014.20140926.35254-6build1                amd64        Binaries for TeX Live
ii  texlive-extra-utils                                  2014.20141024-1                            all          TeX Live: TeX auxiliary programs
ii  texlive-font-utils                                   2014.20141024-1                            all          TeX Live: Graphics and font utilities
ii  texlive-fonts-extra                                  2014.20141024-1                            all          TeX Live: Additional fonts
iHR texlive-fonts-extra-doc                              2014.20141024-1                            all          (no description available)
ii  texlive-generic-recommended                          2014.20141024-2ubuntu1                     all          TeX Live: Generic recommended packages
ii  texlive-latex-base                                   2014.20141024-2ubuntu1                     all          TeX Live: LaTeX fundamental packages
ii  texlive-latex-recommended                            2014.20141024-2ubuntu1                     all          TeX Live: LaTeX recommended packages
ii  texlive-pictures                                     2014.20141024-2ubuntu1                     all          TeX Live: Graphics, pictures, diagrams
ii  texlive-pstricks                                     2014.20141024-1         

               all          TeX Live: PSTricks
```

and:

```
>apt-cache policy texlive-fonts-extra-doc
texlive-fonts-extra-doc:
  Installed: 2014.20141024-1
  Candidate: 2014.20141024-1
  Version table:
     2014.20141024-1 0
        500 http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2014.20141024-1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `dpkg -l | grep texlive`

Comment: done! output added

Comment: And the output of `apt-cache policy texlive-fonts-extra-doc`

Comment: added (after the commands done in your suggested answer)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with `python-numpy`. The cause is a previous installation of `texlive`.

Change your download server

```
sudo sed -i 's://ch\.://:g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Reinstall the package

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get install --reinstall texlive-fonts-extra-doc
```

And as you said, you have only 500 MB RAM for your virtual machine

> ```
> $ free -m
> total used free shared buffers cached
> Mem: 489 469 19 8 2 70
> -/+ buffers/cache: 396 92
> Swap: 0 0 0
> ```

give your system more RAM **=)**

Comment: The apt-get install produced the same error

Comment: Change your download server. I have added the command into my answer.

Comment: The command `sudo apt-get update` ended with the same error as I reported in my original question: `E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.`. Should I continue?

Comment: One of these days =) `sudo apt-get clean; sudo apt-get install -f; sudo apt-get install --reinstall texlive-fonts-extra-doc`

Comment: After that, I need the output of `apt-cache policy texlive-fonts-extra-doc` again

Comment: I was unable to run the command `sudo apt-get install -f`. Make an educated guess on the error message...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29036/discussion-between-a-b-and-alex).